# Can't install Enthought Canopy 1.4.1 64-bit on Windows 7 Professional with Service Pack 1

Tags: windows, enthought

I'm trying to install Enthought Canopy 1.4.1 64-bit on Windows 7 Professional with Service Pack 1 and have confirmed the MD5 hash of my file download matches the reference value on the Enthought website.

Double clicking the installer brings up an error message:

"The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher."

However, the system information in the control panel indicates it is a 64-bit operating system.

I also tried right clicking and using "Run as administrator" and get a different error message:

"Windows cannot find 'C:\path to my desktop\canopy-1.4.1-win-64.msi.exe'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again."

Canopy 1.4.1 32-bit also gives me the exact same behavior.  Any ideas about what might be wrong?

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! This is a bad question. I recommend you read [the entire Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and head back when you have a specific, programming-related question.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you think it's a bad question?  Enthought directs questions here: https://support.enthought.com/home

Comment: No, I won't elaborate, but the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) will! A 3rd-party (ie, Enthought) telling their users to ask questions on StackOverflow does not automatically make those questions good or on-topic.

Comment: Yes, we've read the information in the help center.  Enthought Canopy is a software tool commonly used by programmers and in our opinion this is a practical / answerable question unique to software development.  We have provided all of the information we currently have to help diagnose the problem, although we were not able to include screenshots due to StackOverflow restrictions on the ability to include images.

Comment: It appears you have not read the entire Help Center, as your post does not show what research you have already done.

Answer (score 1):

Responded via Enthought Support, but copying here for the record. The second error message states the downloaded file is named "canopy-1.4.1-win-64.msi.exe", which implies the user's browser appended '.exe' onto an already valid '.msi' installer (the Enthought webpage only supplies MSI installers for Windows). Typically, this unwanted addition occurs when downloading Windows installers from within a non-Windows environment (mostly observed with Chrome on OS X).

Solution should be to remove the '.exe' portion in the filename and retry the installation.